# Theano not running on Windows

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

I am trying to install theano on windows using python 3.4. I am following this instruction [Theano on Windows](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows)

Its creating one file called **Theano.egg-link** inside python **Lib/site-packages**

but i am getting this error when trying to call *import theano*

[image]

i used `python setup.py develop` and it gave me this window. which indicating everything installed fine. any help?

[image]

Comment: When did you download theano? This error is not in the current version on github

Comment: @TimCastelijns i just downloaded theano .. using `git clone https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --branch rel-0.7` comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can most likely be fixed by [redownloading the theano project](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip).

As you can see [here](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%2C+e0), the code that is giving you that error is not in the current codebase anymore. It now looks like this

```
def dot(l, r):
    """Return a symbolic matrix/dot product between l and r """
    rval = NotImplemented
    e0, e1 = None, None

    if rval == NotImplemented and hasattr(l, '__dot__'):
        try:
            rval = l.__dot__(r)
        except Exception as e0:
            rval = NotImplemented
    if rval == NotImplemented and hasattr(r, '__rdot__'):
        try:
            rval = r.__rdot__(l)
        except Exception as e1:
            rval = NotImplemented
    if rval == NotImplemented:
        raise NotImplementedError("Dot failed for the following reasons:",
                                  (e0, e1))
    return rval
```

Comment: i tried to follow the link you posted here. but still no luck 
previously i tried `git clone https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --branch rel-0.7 code` 
and it seems your link also contain the same version

Comment: btw after downloading the repo i typed `python setup.py develop`

Comment: @jquery404 I suppose you could manually edit the `__init__.py` in `theano\theano\` and change `, e0:` to `as e0:` to fix that syntax error